# User details logging

Tags: java, logging

I have written this logic for logging, but is getting replication for all fields (last name, DOB,city, state, ZIP, etc). Here only validation logic is going to differ, whereas logging functionality will remain the same.

```
public boolean validFirstName(UserInputDetails record) {
        if (CommonUtil.isNullOrEmpty(record.getFirstName())) {
            record.setErrorCode(ErrorCodes.FIRSTNAME_NULL.getErrorCode());
            if(record.isDetailedLoggingEnabled()){
                Map<String,String> dtlLogMap = new HashMap<>(5);
                dtlLogMap.put("transId",String.valueOf(record.getTransactionId()));
                dtlLogMap.put("firstName",record.getFirstName());
                dtlLogMap.put("validationName","VALID_FIRSTNAME_CHECK");
                dtlLogMap.put("validationStatus","Errored");
                dtlLogMap.put("errorCode",record.getErrorCode());
                DetailedLogger.log(dtlLogMap);
            }
            return false;
        }
        
        if ( record.getFirstName().length() >=50) {
            record.setErrorCode(ErrorCodes.FIRSTNAME_INVALID_LENGTH.getErrorCode());
            if(record.isDetailedLoggingEnabled()){
                Map<String,String> dtlLogMap = new HashMap<>(6);
                dtlLogMap.put("transId",String.valueOf(record.getTransactionId()));
                dtlLogMap.put("firstName",record.getFirstName());
                dtlLogMap.put("firstNameLength",returnStringifNotNull(record.getFirstName().length()));
                dtlLogMap.put("validationName","VALID_FIRSTNAME_LENGTH_CHECK");
                dtlLogMap.put("validationStatus","Errored");
                dtlLogMap.put("errorCode",record.getErrorCode());
                DetailedLogger.log(dtlLogMap);
            }
            return false;
        }
        if(record.isDetailedLoggingEnabled()){
            Map<String,String> dtlLogMap = new HashMap<>(4);
            dtlLogMap.put("transId",String.valueOf(record.getTransactionId()));
            dtlLogMap.put("firstName",record.getFirstName());
            dtlLogMap.put("validationName","VALID_FIRSTNAME_CHECK");
            dtlLogMap.put("validationStatus","passed");
            DetailedLogger.log(dtlLogMap);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: i'm not sure how to say but have you considered putting some logic in methods?

Comment: Adding key value combination in hashmap and logging will be the same for validation success Or failure. Only key and value will be change... is there any way to write this code in jeneric method to avoid duplication of code?

Comment: `if (record.getFirstName().length() <=50) { return false; }` Are you sure you want to fail when a first name is shorter than 50 characters?

Comment: One side-note: creating a `HashMap` with size `n` for `n` elements is *not* what you want, as the map will be resized after reaching the size `n * 0.75`, i.e. you will *always* have a resize operation of the map. As this is microoptimization anyway, just leave the parameter out.

Comment: Have you tested this code? Does it produce the results you expect? If the results are wrong, it's not ready for review yet.

Comment: @marc I changed to >

Comment: @mtj it will populate only n key and value pair , I will not add it after that

Comment: @Vasanth Create a map with size 5, add 5 elements (which you do) step into the put-method calls in a debugger, and see that the map resizes. Then, read the docs again, to gather the meanings of size and load factor in a hash map.

Comment: `returnStringifNotNull(record.getFirstName().length())` looks *wrong*, in addition to *uncalled for* after `isNullOrEmpty(record.getFirstName())`.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Zeta I am not changed the question , I am just re-frame the question and added some more method for clear understanding .

Comment: @greybeard please ignore that , that is typo , i just mock it manually for review.

Comment: @mtj  i have removed the parameter.

Comment: @Zeta thanks for having a look at it...

Answer (score 5):

as mentioned in the comments it might be helpful to **[extract methods](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method)** to remove redundant code - you might want to read a more detailed explanation on ["methods in java"](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm) to gain basic knowledge on methods.

tl;dr

*"A Java method is a collection of statements that are grouped together to perform an operation"*

let's collect your your statements that all checks have in common

```
Map<String,String> dtlLogMap = new HashMap<>(4);
dtlLogMap.put("transId",String.valueOf(record.getTransactionId()));
dtlLogMap.put("firstName",record.getFirstName());
dtlLogMap.put("validationName","VALID_FIRSTNAME_CHECK");
dtlLogMap.put("validationStatus","passed");
DetailedLogger.log(dtlLogMap);
```

we can extract a lot of stuff here into a method named `Map<String,String> createLog(Record record, String checkResult)` - noteworthy is, that we only group things together, that belong together - we do not (yet) extract the logging action - to maintain the **[Single Responsibility-principle](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Single_Responsibility_Principle_SRP)**. That makes it also a lot easier to find proper method names (instead of creating an obfucasting method name `createAndPrintLog()`)

```
private Map<String,String> createLog(Record record, String checkName, String checkResult){
    Map<String,String> logs= new HashMap<>(4);
    logs.put("transId",String.valueOf(record.getTransactionId()));
    logs.put("firstName",record.getFirstName());
    logs.put("validationName",checkName);
    logs.put("validationStatus",checkResult);
    return logs;
}
```

note that a method has parameters that let you control the output of the method: the parameters should be self-explaining ([**Tell - dont Ask**](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-4-green/#Tell_dont_ask))

we can now apply this method in your checks and remove redundant code

```
...
if(record.isDetailedLoggingEnabled()){
    //here: method call instead of redundancy
    Map<String,String> dtlLogMap = createLogs(record,"VALID_FIRSTNAME_CHECK",  "Errored");
    dtlLogMap.put("errorCode",record.getErrorCode());
    DetailedLogger.log(dtlLogMap);
}
...
```

### use more methods to remove more reduncancy!

Comment: Its correct for single field ie firstName, If we apply this method ie createLogs() for  more then one  fields (last name, DOB,city, state,zip code) - there should be mapping, So question is how i can write the  Generic method to receive the field name,field value ,error code ,message , transaction id ,status ? these arguments may grow or shrink based on validation pass or failure . Please refer the code

Comment: thanks for pointing that part out! these requirements were not described clearly in your question **Believe in your ideas!** - if you feel you need some kind of Mapping then create a `Mapper`. Always keep in mind to [segregate concerns](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Separation_of_Concerns_SoC): Things from the Model (in your case: `UserInputDetails`) should know how to create its proper log, while the results don't belong to that model